# jQuery Accordion with auto next

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have an accordion that clicks through fine but I need it to also go through to the next slide after 3 seconds. I have searched and found an idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777133/how-to-add-auto-rotation-to-a-jquery-horizontal-accordion) but cant seem to make it function in tandem with it's actual click counterpart. Any ideas greatly appreciated!

```
/* Part 1 -> Set first to active */
jQuery("#accordionBackground .theSlide:first").addClass('active');
/* Part 2 -> Auto change */
$theNextSlide = jQuery(this).next('.theSlide');
    if($theNextSlide.length==0){$theNextSlide=jQuery('.theSlide:first');}
     $next.find('.theSlide').triggerHandler('click');
},3000);
/* Part 3 -> Manual change */
jQuery("#accordionBackground .theSlide").click(function(){
    jQuery("#accordionBackground .theSlide").not(this).animate({width: "35px"}, {duration:'fast', queue:false});
    jQuery("#accordionBackground .theSlide").not(this).removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');

    jQuery(this).next('.theSlide').addClass('nextSlide');
    jQuery(this).animate({width: "588px"}, {duration:'fast', queue:false});


});
```

Thanks, Dan

### EDIT

Further attempt, still no luck though! ->

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout('accordionAutoNext()',3000);
});

function autoNext(){
    $theNextSlide = jQuery(this).next();
    if($theNextSlide.length==0){$theNextSlide=jQuery('.theSlide:first');}
     $next.find('.theSlide').triggerHandler('click');
};
```

Comment: this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11504398/1428241

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

```
/* Part 1 -> Set first to active */
jQuery("#accordionBackground .theSlide:first").addClass('active');
/* Part 2 -> Manual change */
jQuery("#accordionBackground .theSlide").click(function(){
    jQuery("#accordionBackground .theSlide").not(this).animate({width: "35px"}, {duration:'fast', queue:false});
    jQuery("#accordionBackground .theSlide").not(this).removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');

    jQuery(this).next('.theSlide').addClass('nextSlide');
    jQuery(this).animate({width: "588px"}, {duration:'fast', queue:false});
});
/* Part 3 -> Auto change */
var nextAccordion = function(){
    $theNextSlide = jQuery('.theSlide.active').next('.theSlide');
    if($theNextSlide.length==0){$theNextSlide=jQuery('.theSlide:first');}
     $theNextSlide.trigger('click');
};
setInterval(nextAccordion,6000);
/*End accordion */
```